# For/In Loop through JavaScript Data

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

***Before being redirected to a similar question:*** I checked related questions. I understand the thing. I just can't seem to apply it to my specific code correctly.

I'm trying to display JSON data using Javascript. It worked perfectly fine. Then I added one level, and now I'm completely lost.

Initially, I had my overall data (1), my 3 entries (2), and the 3 properties of each entry (3).

I grabbed the data like this:

```
var objDisplay = document.getElementById('myDiv');

for (key1 in this.jsonObj){ 

    for (var x = 0; x < this.jsonObj[key1].length; x++){ 
        var objEntry = document.createElement('div'); 

        for (key2 in this.jsonObj[key1][x]){

            var sPropertyData = this.jsonObj[key1][x][key2]; 
            var objProperty = document.createElement('div');
            objProperty.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sPropertyData));
            objEntry.appendChild(objProperty);

        }

        objDisplay.appendChild(objEntry);
    }

}
```

Now I want to triple the entries and split them into sections, so I'll have my overall data (1), my 3 sections (2), the 3 entries of each section (3), and the 3 properties of each entry (4). I also want to display each section in a separate div.

I know the answer is probably ridiculously easy to figure out with the foundation I have, but I just can't visualize it right now, and my attempts led to...weird results. Help?

**edit:** The new data object, where each letter is a section

```
{
    "ABC": [

        {"A": 
            [
                { "1" : "A1-1", "2" : "A1-2", "3" : "A1-3"},
                { "1" : "A2-1", "2" : "A2-2", "3" : "A2-3" },
                { "1" : "A3-1", "2" : "A3-2", "3" : "A3-3" }
            ]
        },

        {"B": 
            [
                { "1" : "B1-1", "2" : "B1-2", "3" : "B1-3"},
                { "1" : "B2-1", "2" : "B2-2", "3" : "B2-3" },
                { "1" : "B3-1", "2" : "B3-2", "3" : "B3-3" }
            ]
        },

        {"C": 
            [
                { "1" : "C1-1", "2" : "C1-2", "3" : "C1-3"},
                { "1" : "C2-1", "2" : "C2-2", "3" : "C2-3" },
                { "1" : "C3-1", "2" : "C3-2", "3" : "C3-3" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**edit 2:** Expected output (don't mind the class names, they're for reference only)

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="entry">
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="entry">
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="entry">
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
        <div class="property">stringified json data</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The only data I need textually is the value of the lowest level, but I need to be able to use the higher levels for styling purposes (see created divs in initial code).

Comment: prepare a spicy fiddle demo

Comment: Seeing the actual json structure is relatively important to being able to iterate over it.

Comment: and, what exactly is your expected output? (please provide html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use for in loops for looping over objects, instead use array forEach with object.keys. Otherwise, you forgot to iterate over the inner-most object. However, a recursive function could make this work regardless of how deep you nest it, assuming you keep the same structure of *Object > Array > Object > String*

```js
var jsonObj = {
  "ABC": [

    {
      "A": [{
        "1": "A1-1",
        "2": "A1-2",
        "3": "A1-3"
      }, {
        "1": "A2-1",
        "2": "A2-2",
        "3": "A2-3"
      }, {
        "1": "A3-1",
        "2": "A3-2",
        "3": "A3-3"
      }]
    },

    {
      "B": [{
        "1": "B1-1",
        "2": "B1-2",
        "3": "B1-3"
      }, {
        "1": "B2-1",
        "2": "B2-2",
        "3": "B2-3"
      }, {
        "1": "B3-1",
        "2": "B3-2",
        "3": "B3-3"
      }]
    },

    {
      "C": [{
        "1": "C1-1",
        "2": "C1-2",
        "3": "C1-3"
      }, {
        "1": "C2-1",
        "2": "C2-2",
        "3": "C2-3"
      }, {
        "1": "C3-1",
        "2": "C3-2",
        "3": "C3-3"
      }]
    }
  ]
};
var objDisplay = document.getElementById('myDiv');

function recurse(obj, level) {
  console.log(level);
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  switch (level) {
    case 1:
      div.className = 'section';
      break;
    case 2:
      div.className = 'entry';
      break;
    case 3:
      div.className = 'property';
      break;
  }
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'string') {
      var prop = document.createElement('div');
      prop.className = 'property';
      var tempObj = {};
      tempObj[key] = obj[key]
      prop.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(tempObj)))
      div.appendChild(prop);
      return;
    }
    obj[key].forEach(function(obj) {
      div.appendChild(recurse(obj,level + 1));
    });
  });
  return div;
}

objDisplay.appendChild(recurse(jsonObj,0));
```

```css
.section {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.entry {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.property {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: unfortunately there's an extra div, probably couldn't be too hard to remove.

Comment: Gotcha. That's a really simple way of doing it! What if I want to code it the "arborescent" way, like my example above? Your answer works great if I'm doing a simple output, but if I want to add classes or squeeze additional content in straight from the Javascript, it's not ideal.

Comment: All depends on your  needs. You could solve that by adding a "level" counter to the loop that simply counts how many levels you are nested inside the recursion, and use that level number to decide what class to add. Or, you can add the classes after the fact based on how nested the divs are.